# Python, while loop conflicts with other buttons in simpledialog

Tags: python, while-loop, simpledialog

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a typeracer kind of program but the while loop conflicts with other buttons in simpledialog(including the close button), making it impossible to quit halfway without ending the main.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime
import time
start = time.time()
answer = "She sells seashells on the seashore"
rounds = 1    
messagebox.showinfo("TypeRacer","Test your typing speed by typing various texts as fast as possible.")
while rounds != 3:
    question = simpledialog.askstring("Round "+str(rounds),answer)
    if question != answer:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!","Incorrect syntax")
    elif question == answer:
        messagebox.showinfo("You got it right!","Proceeding to the next round.")
        rounds += 1
end = time.time()
f1 = end - start
f2 = int(f1)
f2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(f2)
f3 = f2.strftime("%M:%S")
messagebox._show("Well done!","Your time was: "+str(f3))
```

Comment: Consider whether you really want the interface to work this way for a typing test. Doing it this way,  it will count time that the user spends dismissing the dialog boxes, positioning the insertion point in the new dialog, etc.

Comment: Anyway, it's not really clear to me what you mean by "interfere" or "quit" here; but you should look up the concept of a dialog box being *modal* in the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do and what is the problem (i didn't run code) but usually any loop is wrong idea in any GUI (not only in `tktiner`) because it blocks `mainloop()` which handles all events and widgets. maybe you should use one standrad window and display message in `Label` inside window.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. So is it better if I make my own dialogs? I tried looking it up and I think making my own dialog should fix it. I think.